# Creating a holding hand animation?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

[image]

What are some approaches to creating an animation where the bone from Armature A controls the bone from Armature B?

I tried Child Of constraint, but the hand is always out of sync when I move the parent's hand around.

Answer (score 0):

Id say probably consider animating at the same keyframe

One 3D model is reaching for a hand at a keyframe then select the other 3D model do the same at that exact keyframe!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).